# Why I am still charged after removing all S3 resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I deleted my Amazon S3 resources, but I still see charges for S3. I have only one 
bucket and it is empty, for some reason I am not able to delete it.

It does not have any logging or something, all properties are displayed in below picture. 
[image]

Comment: Doesn't Bill Details show the exact itemized charges?  My guess is there are still requests to your resources and those get charged even though the resources are no longer there.

Answer (score 4):

A likely cause of an "empty" bucket that isn't actually empty is abandoned multipart uploads that were never completed or aborted.

Use [`aws s3api list-multipart-uploads`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/list-multipart-uploads.html) to verify this.

If they are there, you can [`aws s3api abort-multipart-upload`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/abort-multipart-upload.html) to delete each one, after which you should be able to delete them.

Or, create a lifecycle policy to purge them, see https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/automating-lifecycle-rules-for-multipart-uploads-in-amazon-s3/.